# League of Legends items that grant allies bonuses

Tags: league-of-legends

I play Lulu and find her quite a good support. So I want to equip her with the most items that grant allies bonus stats.

My [google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%22league%20of%20legends%22%20items%20that%20grant%20ally%20status) comes up little help, so I ask here.

One clutch item I found is the [Righteous Glory](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/item/righteous-glory-253) that gives bonus speed-then-slowing-explosion to nearby allies.

What else grants bonuses to allies?

Comment: Note that choosing which items to use is situational - e.g. Lulu isn't a good choice to build FotM as she doesn't usually go for HP items, Abyssal is usually built by mid so building on support is a waste, Censer depends on ADC being AS-based, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are all I can recall currently.

- **[Locket of the Iron Solari](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Locket_of_the_Iron_Solari)** has an active shield for allies.
- <del>**[Captain enchantment](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Captain)** for any type boots will give bonus move speed to nearby allies.</del> -Removed in [Patch 6.9](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-69-notes)
- **[Ardent Censer](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ardent_Censer)** gives allies that you shield or heal bonus attack speed and on hit magic dmg.
- **[Athene's Unholy Grail](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Athene%27s_Unholy_Grail)** heals allies that you shield or heal based on the stored damage you have done to enemies.
- **[Zeke's Convergence](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zeke's_Harbinger)** gives the ally it is bound to bonus auto attack magic damage when it procs via ultimate cast.
- **[Shurelya's Reverie](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Shurelya's_Reverie)** gives a brief movement speed buff to nearby allies.
- <del>[**Face of the Mountain**](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Face_of_the_Mountain) grants the target ally a shield based on a percent of their maximum HP.</del> Removed
- **[Elixir of Iron](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elixir_of_Iron)** causes your champion to leave a path that grants allied champions bonus move speed.
- <del>**[Abyssal Scepter](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Abyssal_Scepter)** causes your enemies to lose magic resist, which effectively grants your allies bonus magic pen.</del> Removed
- **[Abyssal Mask](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Abyssal_Mask)** causes your enemies to take increased magic damage, which effectively grants your allies a magic damage buff.
- **[Mikael's Crucible](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mikael's_Crucible)** Removes all stuns, roots, taunts, fears, silences and slows on an allied champion

***Non-Items***

- <del>**[Windspeakers Blessing](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Windspeaker's_Blessing_(Season_2016_Mastery))** Gives allies that you heal or shield bonus magic resist and armor. This is one of the keystone masteries in the cunning tree.</del> Removed

Comment: Also **Windspeaker's Blessing** keystone mastery: *"Your heals and shields are 10% stronger. Additionally, heals and shields on allies increase your target's armor by 5 - 22 (based on level) and magic resistance by 2.5 - 11 (based on level) for 3 seconds. "*. Granted, it is not an item, but still gives bonuses to allies.

Comment: @clcto while this mastery is certainly helpful, it isn't an item, and the OP asked for items, thus i did not include it on my list

Comment: @Dragonrage What your `MR` stands for?

Comment: @NamGVU it stands for Magic Resist

Comment: Abyssal Scepter may fit in here. Lowering the enemy's MR technically has the same effect as giving allies more AP.

Comment: Relic Shield and Targon's Brace give a nearby ally gold and health.

Comment: @Dragonrage How can we get `Windspeakers Calling`? Is it a mastery?

Comment: @NamGVU yes. it is in the cunning tree

Comment: If you're doing heals and shields, you're missing Mikael's Crucible. But a nice list in general.

Comment: @ChronoD I was focusing solely on buffs, but I did include FotM which only gives a shield, so I suppose I should add in Mikael's Crucible.

Comment: @Tylor Lowering enemy MR technically has the same effect as giving allies more *magic penetration*, not AP. It's a subtle distinction, but important because some champions scale really well off of pure AP (Veigar, for example) but others do much better with penetration (Lissandra, Teemo).